# cambiar el tipo de dato para una consulta en Yii2

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2

Tengo un error al intentar filtrar por números y letras a una base de datos postgres a través del Framework Yii2

los campos de la base de datos son id_alumno tipo int, nombre y apellidos tipo varchar

al momento de realizar la consulta le da el siguiente error

> No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
> The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "alumnos" WHERE (("id_alumno" LIKE '%gutierrez%') OR ("nombre" LIKE '%gutierrez%')) OR ("apellidos" LIKE '%gutierrez%')

el codigo de la consulta es

```
$table = Alumnos::find()
                     ->where(["like","id_alumno", "$search"])
                     ->orWhere(["like","nombre", "$search"])
                     ->orWhere(["like","apellidos", "$search"]);
```

al hacerlo en una  cade de texto lo coloco de la siguiente forma y funciona,

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE nombre LIKE '%$search%'";
    //         $query .= "OR apellidos LIKE '%$search%'";
    //         $query .= "OR CAST (id_alumno AS TEXT) LIKE '%$search%'";
    //         $model = $table->findBySql($query)->all();
```

pero al hacerlo en la forma activeRecord no se colo hacer el tipo de cambio de int a varchar.

cabe destacar que esta consulta se ejecuta a traves de un filtro, por le cual debo filtrar por nombre, apellidos o el id del alumno.

Comment: Pero tu problema es la consulta en sí misma, estás queriendo usar `gutierrez` o lo que sea como condición para la columna `id_alumno` la cual, supongo, es numérica y de ahí el error.

Comment: exacto es como comente un campo de filtro donde se podrá colocar el id, el nombre o los apellidos y es necesario que ese único campo de filtro permita filtrar por texto o numérico

Comment: Pues entonces no uses `like` para el primer filtro: `->where(["id_alumno", "$search"])
                     ->orWhere(["like","nombre", "$search"])
                     ->orWhere(["like","apellidos", "$search"])`. De todos modos suena muy raro querer mezclar un id con otros tipos de filtros... en fin.

Answer (score 0):

[Según la documentación](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/es/db-query-builder#where), si usas `like`  te va a rodear, sí o sí, el criterio por el wildcard `%`, produciendo una consulta errónea en el caso de `id_alumno`.

Entonces tienes dos soluciones:

#### 1. No usar `like` para los valores numéricos:

Sería lo propio para tales casos.

```
$table = Alumnos::find()
                     ->where(["id_alumno", "$search"])
                     ->orWhere(["like","nombre", "$search"])
                     ->orWhere(["like","apellidos", "$search"]);
```

#### 2. Hacer un CAST

Aunque esto no tendría mucho sentido, para el caso del `id_alumno` ...

```
$table = Alumnos::find()
                     ->where(["like", "CAST (id_alumno) AS TEXT", "$search"])
                     ->orWhere(["like","nombre", "$search"])
                     ->orWhere(["like","apellidos", "$search"]);
```

O bien:

```
$table = Alumnos::find()
                     ->where(["like", "id_alumno", (string)"$search"])
                     ->orWhere(["like","nombre", "$search"])
                     ->orWhere(["like","apellidos", "$search"]);
```